# How to solve the equations of linear combination of sigmoid functions?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, neural-networks

Let $\sigma(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ be the sigmoid function.

How to solve such kind of equations?
\begin{align*}
\sigma(x+y)+\sigma(x-y)=a\\
\sigma(2x+y)+3\sigma(3x-y)=b\\
\end{align*}

I guess this kind of equations are related to neural networks. I don't know how to solve it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This is neither differential equations nor linear programming nor optimization.

Comment: Sorry. I don't find a proper tag. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $e^{-x} = s$ and $e^{-y} = t$, the system becomes
$$ \eqalign{ {\frac {s{t}^{2}+s+2\,t}{ \left( st+1 \right)  \left( t+s
 \right) }}&=a\cr {\frac {3\,{s}^{2}{t}^{2}+{s}^{3}+4\,t}{ \left( {s}^{2}t
+1 \right)  \left( {s}^{3}+t \right) }}&=b }
$$
Multiply by the denominators and you have a system of polynomial equations.
Take the resultant with respect to $t$, disregard factors of $s$ and $s-1$,
and you get a rather awful irreducible polynomial in one variable $s$ of degree $9$:
$$  \left( {a}^{2}{b}^{2}-2\,a{b}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) {s}^{9}+ \left( {a}
^{2}b-a{b}^{2}-ab+{b}^{2} \right) {s}^{8}+ \left( -{a}^{2}{b}^{2}+4\,{
a}^{2}b-4\,ab+{b}^{2} \right) {s}^{7}+ \left( -{a}^{2}{b}^{2}+{a}^{2}b
+3\,a{b}^{2}+3\,{a}^{2}-7\,ab-{b}^{2}+2\,b \right) {s}^{6}+ \left( -{a
}^{2}{b}^{2}+2\,{a}^{2}b+4\,a{b}^{2}+4\,{a}^{2}-12\,ab-2\,{b}^{2}-2\,a
+6\,b+1 \right) {s}^{5}+ \left( {a}^{2}{b}^{2}-6\,{a}^{2}b+4\,{a}^{2}+
4\,ab-2\,{b}^{2}-2\,a+6\,b-5 \right) {s}^{4}+ \left( {a}^{2}{b}^{2}-7
\,{a}^{2}b-a{b}^{2}+9\,{a}^{2}+11\,ab-{b}^{2}-16\,a+4 \right) {s}^{3}+
 \left( {a}^{2}{b}^{2}-4\,{a}^{2}b-4\,a{b}^{2}+20\,ab+3\,{b}^{2}-16\,a
-16\,b+16 \right) {s}^{2}+ \left( {a}^{2}b-a{b}^{2}-4\,{a}^{2}+5\,ab+{
b}^{2}-4\,a-6\,b+8 \right) s-{a}^{2}{b}^{2}+8\,{a}^{2}b+2\,a{b}^{2}-16
\,{a}^{2}-16\,ab-{b}^{2}+32\,a+8\,b-16
=0$$

So you're not going to get a nice "closed form" solution, although this still might be useful in some cases. Numerical methods are probably the way to go.

EDIT: Given particular values of $a$ and $b$, things might not be too bad.
For example, let's try $a = 5/4$, $b = 31/10$.  The polynomial in $s$ is
$$961\,{s}^{9}-2294\,{s}^{8}-2449\,{s}^{7}+29\,{s}^{6}+563\,{s}^{5}-667
\,{s}^{4}+279\,{s}^{3}+513\,{s}^{2}-54\,s-81
$$
This has three real roots (as can be confirmed using Sturm's theorem).  To get a numerical value, you need numerical methods.  In this case the values are approximately $s =.4709506665, .5829071971, 3.174092780 $.
The corresponding $t$ values are  approximately $.2667682226$,
$0.6205142034$, $-0.06730377237$.  We're not interested in the third solution since we need $s,t>0$.  The first two give $(x,y) = (-\log(s), -\log(t)) = (.7530019325, 1.321375078)$ and $(.5397272869, .4772067843)$ respectively.

Comment: So horrible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I may ask, how did you select these values for $a,b$ ?

Comment: I wanted a case that had some roots.  $s=1/2, t = 1/3$ give approximately $a = 1.257$, $b = 3.105$.

Answer (score 2):

If $z$ is small, you can write $$\sigma(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z}{4}+O\left(z^2\right)$$ and then the solutions of the equations write $$x=2 (a-1)$$ $$y=11 a-2 b-7$$ If this is not the case, Robert Israel gave the rigorous answer.